# How to set background image for IcsSpinner and its drop down view resource using action bar sherlock in android

Tags: actionbarsherlock

How to add style for IcsSpinner using action bar sherlock in android. If anyone know how to set different background image for IcsSpinner and Drop down view resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background</item>
</style>
```

Check out [ActionBar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)